# Google smartlock passwords incorrectly prompting to save an SSN field

Tags: google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

I have a form with an SSN field which I am allowing the user to toggle visibility on and off of. Problem is when they submit the data google prompts to store their password even though its not a password and it attempts to associate the field above it, which is date of birth, as their username. Is there a way to tell chrome not to do this?

**EDIT:**

My fields are writted in Angular, and have a bunch of extra directives in them which control behavior but the only attributes

```
<input
    id="input-ssn"
    placeholder="{{ 'PlaceHolder.SSNOrITIN' | translate }}"
    ssnFormat
    formControlName="ssn"
    #ssnInput
    type="tel"
    [scrollIntoViewOnFocus]="true"
    [timedVisibility]="3002"
    [visibilityTimerActive]="ssnVisibilityTimerActive"                            
    (visibilityChange)="handleSSNVisibilityChangedByTimer($event)"
/>
```

Switching the field to be invisible changes the type to `type="password"`

Comment: Can you post the form attributes you are using for the fields? (or link to the page itself)

Comment: @StevenSoneff I updated it with more information on my field; My guess is that because the type becomes password it triggers the prompt, I just dont know how to disable it while keeping the type=password